# What does "You (don't) want to do something" mean while explaining?

Tags: spoken-english

What does it mean when someone explains something to me?

> You want to *do this*.
>   You do not want to *do this*.

Is this equal to `You should/shouldn't do this`?

(instead of "do this" would be something different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use 'want' to state a goal, long or short term: I want to be a doctor; I want to go home early this afternoon. We can use 'you want' and 'you don't want' to say that something is desirable or the opposite, and, when explaining a task or process to someone, we can use 'want' to emphasise a goal or objective contained in that task: when pouring wine, you want to get it all in the glass - you don't want to get any on the table.

> 2 informal with infinitive Should or need to do something.
>
> ‘you don't want to believe everything you hear’

[Want (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/want)